# I am returning an array of string in this code but still it says this method must return a result of type String. why?

Tags: java

The return type is an array of String. I returned that array but still the error message is shown.

```
public static String[] get_dept_list()
    {
        establishConnection();
        try
        {
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            sql = "select * from DEPARTMENT_LIST";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            System.out.println("Query Ran");
            int in=-1; 
            String name [] = {};
            while(rs.next())
            {
                in++;
            }
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            name = new String [in+1];
            in=-1;
            while(rs.next())
            {
                name[++in] = rs.getString("DEPT_NAME");
            }
            return name;
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Problem in finding the dept_name_list");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `String name [] = {};` - That's not doing what you meant to do.

Comment: Because when there is an exception (control goes to catch block), you are not returning anything. Probably return null, so that you can differentiate in the caller scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the exception is caught, you have to make sure to return an array too.

```
catch (SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Problem in finding the dept_name_list");
        return new String[] { };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error message because your only `return` is on your `try - catch` block. Try to put one in your catch or outside the `try - catch`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that the method **must** return a `String[]`.

In the case were an exception is thrown and you enter your catch statement, no return is made.

Either refactor your code to return a default `String[]` or allow the exception to propagate.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a `return null` or a return `new String[] { };` at the end of your function.

Answer (score 0):

What if the code throws `SQLExecption`? The control will reach to the `catch` block and then after the catch block, there is no return statement.

Change your code to something like this:

```
public static String[] get_dept_list()

    String [] name = null;

    try {
        ...
        name = new String [in+1];
        ...
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        ...
    }

    return name;
}
```

So irrespective of whether the code will throw exception, the last line of the method will always be executed and thus you are making sure that your method always returns a String array.

Answer (score 0):

If you get an SQLException, your code won't return anything. You are probably getting one.

Verify the console for any outputs and put a return statement inside the catch or after it.

Answer (score 0):

move your `name` variable declaration above try - catch block

and re-assign it to `null` when exception occures,  as it is easier to check `null` condition

```
public static String[] get_dept_list()
    {
        String name [] = null;
        establishConnection();
        try
        {
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            sql = "select * from DEPARTMENT_LIST";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            System.out.println("Query Ran");
            int in=-1; 

            while(rs.next())
            {
                in++;
            }
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            name = new String [in+1];
            in=-1;
            while(rs.next())
            {
                name[++in] = rs.getString("DEPT_NAME");
            }

        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Problem in finding the dept_name_list");
            name = null;
        }finally{
          //close resource intensive connection
          if(stmt != null){
             stmt.close();
          }
          if(conn!= null){
             conn.close();
          }
       }
        return name;
    }
```